# Can't return a superformula in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'd like to show a series of superformula shapes, half of which are one shape and half another. The following works perfectly for just showing one type, `var shape`:

```
var coords = d3.range(n).map(function(i,d) {
    return [(i+1)*w/(n+1) , h/2];
  });    

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
   .data(coords)
   .enter().append("svg:g");

var shape = d3.superformula()
   .type("square")
   .size(4000)
   .segments(360);

var shape2 = d3.superformula()
   .type("triangle")
   .size(4000)
   .segments(360);

g.append("path")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; })  
   .attr("d", shape);
```

However, when I try to change that last line and create a function to return the either superformula shape, nothing shows up:

```
    .attr("d", function(d,i) {if (i < n/2.0){return shape} else {return shape2}});
```

This function does work for normal path variables (e.g. `"M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"`) though. Is there something specific about superformula variables that keeps this from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign the value of an attribute based on a function, you need to call this function. That is, your code assigns the *function* to the `d` attribute and not the return value when called. If you change your code as follows, it should work.

```
.attr("d", function(d,i) {if (i < n/2.0){return shape(d)} else {return shape2(d)}});
```